# Python3.4 - How do I get the PID of a program that was started with Popen? (OS -Raspbian Jessie)

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, popen, kill

**Python 3.4**

**OS** - **Raspbian Jessie** running on a *Raspberry Pi 3*

### **NOTE:** The program "*gnutv*" does NOT have a stop command. It only has an option of a timer to stop the recording.

**My question:**
I'm still fairly new to programming and Python (self/YouTube/books taught). I am writing a program that checks a system for alarms. When an alarm is present, it triggers the program "gnutv" to begin recording video to a file. That was the easy part. I can make the program start, and record video using

```
Popen(["gnutv", "-out", "file", str(Videofile), str(Channel)])
```

The program continues to monitor the alarm inputs while the video is recording so it will know when to stop recording. BUT I can't get it to stop recording when the alarm is no longer present. I've attempted to use kill(), terminate(), and others without success (all returned errors indicating I don't know how to use these more complex commands). *HOWEVER*, I *CAN* kill the process by switching to the terminal and finding the PID using

```
pidof 'gnutv'
```

and then killing it with

```
kill PID#
```

So how can I return the PID value I get *from* the terminal so I can send the kill command *to* the terminal (again using Popen)?
i.e. - `Popen(['kill', 'PID#'])`

Comment: You could try just running `killall gnutv` (providing you don't mind killing *every* instance of GnuTV), so you don't need to capture the terminal output.

Comment: Oddly, I found that very solution 5 minutes after I logged out of StackExchange...lol. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to run the `kill` program itself, you can just call `.kill()` or `.terminate()` on the `Popen` object.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['gnutv', '-out', 'file', str(Videofile), str(Channel)])
# Some time later...

# This is equivalent to running "kill <pid>"
proc.terminate()

# This is equivalent to running "kill -9 <pid>"
proc.kill()
```

If you really need the pid (hint: you don't) you can get it from the object as well, it's stored in the `pid` attribute.

```
print('Spawned gnutv (pid={})'.format(proc.pid))
```

You really should *not* be running the `kill` program, since that program is just a wrapper around the `kill()` function in the first place.  Just call the function directly, or through the wrapper provided by `subprocess`.